# Include editable file in c# .exe

Tags: c#, edit, embedded-resource

I would like to embed a .txt file into my C# project storing a list values for the user. These values should be configurable and therefore the .txt will have to be edited during runtime. I have found out that Embedded Resources cannot be modified. Is there any other way to do that?

Thank you.

Comment: That's usually called a "database"

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1038795/can-i-modify-the-content-of-an-embedded-resource-text-xml-file-in-a-net-appli

Comment: This sounds like you should be using user settings or a database.

Comment: @Darcara, I don't think it's a duplicate of that question.

Answer (score 1):

Store the text file as an embedded resource. The first time your program is run, copy the embedded resource to a file on disk, and use it for the configuration. Your users can edit the disk file.

The embedded resource version serves as a default configuration.

Answer (score 1):

You can use your `app.config` or `web.config` configuration files.

Answer (score 1):

Normall if you will use large amout of data using a database is recommended. I assume you really need just a .txt document. In your assembly write a procedure that will create that text file if its not present. To be more specific lets say your program is mainProgram.exe. In  onload event of mainprogram.exe write a procedure checkTxtFile(). This procedure first will check if there is a txt file in the directory.If the file is not presend it will create it with the desired values.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a XML file using Filestream and using it during runtime or 
make your own protocol format and store the data in the file so that no one can change it.
Over to that you can also encrypt and decrypt the file on the fly.

Answer (score 0):

Lists of modifyable, persistable values are best stored in a database.  There are many lightweight options to choose from; in this case I think a [SqlLite](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/157830-using-sqlite-with-c#/) database would suit your purposes best.